# Angular 6: transfer isAdmin? value from AuthService to AuthGuard canActivate() method

Tags: angular, routes, google-cloud-firestore, auth-guard

Angular 6 & Firestore application.

I am trying to build an `AuthGuard` service with a `canActivate()` method that returns a boolean. The boolean is based on a `UserAuthService` property called `isAdmin`.

The trouble is that `canActivate()` executes before my `UserAuthService` has time to assign a value to the `isAdmin` property. Therefore `isAdmin` returns as `undefined`.

I have tried using `subscribe` and `.map` and `.pipe(map => ())`, all to no avail. I know I'm doing something wrong, but I can't pinpoint what.

Is there a way to force `canActivate()` to wait until `isAdmin` is assigned a value?

Here is the code.

```
// app.routing.ts

import { AuthGuardService as AuthGuard } from './auth-guard.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }
]
```

And the `AuthGuard` service:

```
// auth-guard.service.ts

export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

    constructor(public userauth: UserAuthService,
                public router: Router) {}

    canActivate(): boolean {
      if (this.userauth.isAdmin === true) {
        return true;
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
        return false;
      }
    }
}
```

And the `UserAuthService`:

```
// user-auth.service.ts

export class UserAuthService {
  usersCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<User>;
  user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  isAdmin: boolean;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private afs: AngularFirestore) {
      this.usersCollection = this.afs.collection('users');
      this.user = afAuth.authState;

      this.user.subscribe(user => {
          if (user === null) {
            this.isAdmin = false;
          } else {                
            this.usersCollection.doc(`${user.uid}`).ref.get().then((doc) => {
              this.isAdmin = doc.data().admin; <-- THIS.ISADMIN ASSIGNED VALUE HERE
            });
          }
      });
   }
```

Comment: The duplicate has been removed.

Comment: you can return an Observable<boolean> instead of a boolean from canActivate...

Comment: `canActivate: Observable<boolean> { if (...) { return true; } }` throws the error `type 'true' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'`. Is my syntax correct?

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek How do I return an `Observable<boolean>`? My attempts have been unsuccessful.

Comment: I didn't mean to just literally change the return type. I meant that you can return an actual Observable. How you arrange to get that is something you're going to have to work out.

Comment: @John I am not certain but you may have a few things to check: 1. If you did not show it but typically I have seen that a guard has the Typescript Angular designation '@Injectable()' above the export class.  2. Whatever module you are using typically has to have this declared like a service in the 'providers: [ AuthGuard, SomeService].  3. I often use DevTools with Chrome when debugging any Angular as it often will say something about what is missing if you just have the console up of DevTools.

Comment: @djangojazz Thank you. Yes, `@injectable( )` is in my service. And I've listed `AuthGuardService` as a provider in my `app.module`. My `canActivate()` method works where I need it to (in `app.routing.ts`) if I simply tell it to return true or false. The nature of the problem has to do with how I am collecting the `isAdmin` boolean from `UserAuthService` and then trying to access that boolean value in `AuthGuardService`.

Comment: @john I am away from code but I would also check you may want to set the publicly exposed property as public as well for 'isAdmin' and maybe set up the route navigation to be I think what is 'resolve' option for a route as well.  You mentioned timing so adding a condition that will fire the business logic from your service may work.  Just a thought as I did one of these in a Pluralsite lab.